# Can anybody tell me which font this is?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

I would like to know what font this is, or the name of a similar font.

[image: interesting font]

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure it's Gill Sans MT **bold** (as mentioned by user568458 in the comments) or very close, here's an image with the font and a woven pattern in the background for good measure and ease of comparison.

[image]

And with some custom kerning

[image]

Comment: No problem, welcome to GD.SE and as was mentioned before in future with your questions it's best to show some effort in terms of what you have and haven't tried. With this question for example you could have used our resources for font id ( http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info ) just like @boblet mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

We have a page of [**resources for font identification**](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tags/font-identification/info), and it is always preferable to try these first, and let us know what you have tried. It is always good to show effort.

It is pretty close to **[Humanist condensed bold](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/tilde/humanst-521/bold-condensed/)**

[image]

Or possibly **[Klamat doomsday heavy](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/layarbahtera/kiamat-doomsday/heavy/)**

[image]

Comment: I think its Kiamat Doomsday Heavy from LayarBahtera Kiamat Doomsday based on the 4 and the 8 but Gill Sans MT seems to be from the same type family of styles as well.